# Service stop after manuel start

Tags: c#, service

When i start my service without started parameter, he stop just after starting. When i pass the parameter some int it run in background for ever it's ok.

This service just delete some old file periodicly. I try to pass an default value but with out succed.

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        bool parseOk = false;
        base.OnStart(args);
        parseOk = int.TryParse(args[0], out dayLimit);
        if (!parseOk) dayLimit = 2;

        // Update the service state to Running.
        ServiceStatus serviceStatus = new ServiceStatus()
        {
            dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_RUNNING
        };
        SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);
        // Set up a timer that triggers every minute.
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer
        {
            Interval = 3600000 // 3600000 milisecond = 3600 seconds = 1hrs
        };
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.TimerSuppress_Tick);
        timer.Start();
    }
```

The message i get when he stop is: 'service on local computer stated and stop. Some service stop automatically if ther are not use by other service or programs.' Why it stop? Can I fix it and have the choice between default value and start parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont pass any parameter, this throws an exception

```
parseOk = int.TryParse(args[0], out dayLimit);
```

because args[0] doesnt exists.

Try with

```
if(args.Length > 0)
{
    parseOk = int.TryParse(args[0], out dayLimit);
}
```